# vim special character "^\"

Tags: vim, character, vi

I opened a file in VI and I see a few instances of "^\"  What exactly is this character?

Thanks

Comment: Set cursor to this character and type `ga` in normal mode to get its code.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a [file-separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_separator) ASCII character from [the ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters).

Answer (score 0):

After poking around on Google, it sounds like it generally sends a quit signal (depending on the machine you're on). See the `stty` command to determine what it's mapped to on your box. It also has an unexpected and useful effect when using `ping`, see [this blog post](http://blog.sqawasmi.com/index.php/2009/09/28/ping-tip-ctl-backslash).